# Magento wrong calculation for orders

Tags: php, magento

I am having weird problem here. I think that order calculations are not correct when I have an order with discount.
[image]

As I can tell the problem is with Grand Total(Excl.Tax) which is calculated wrong. But I am not sure how this should be calculated - I know that Subtotal is okay (299 + 549 = 848), Shipping is 159, Discount 500. I am not sure about the total tax field and Grand total (excl tax). Any advices? If someone could help me out, how this should be calculated, that would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

everytime a calculation is perfect from magento but due to some setting from admin our mind set will go in wrong way

there are various setting from admin to check and satisfied our mind to accept that the calculation is correct, no worries here i am giving you very useful link to check whether a calculation is perfect or not

[Document link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/configuration-sales-tax-calculation-settings)

just go to `System > Configuration > Sales > Tax > Calculation Settings`

Comment: yes, I understand that. But my problem is, that I am not sure how the total tax is calculated? Do you maybe know?

Comment: it is depends on your setting with sales->VAT->Manage vat